# continue in for loop after function is done JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have found behaviour that makes me trouble in JavaScript. I have two  functions:

`var show_uploaded = function( data_photo )` that gets informations about uploaded photos as a parameter,

`function exif_like(path){/*working with my image*/ console.log('exif_like END'); }`
that gets path to every single one uploaded photo as a parameter.

I made code like this:

```
var show_uploaded = function( data_photo ){
    for( var z = 0; z < data_photo.length; z++ ){ 
       var send_image_name = uploaded_photo[z].name;
       $.ajax({
            data: { compare : send_image_name },
            url: 'get_panorama.php',
            method: 'POST', // or GET
            success: function( path ){
                exif_like( path );
                console.log('FOR LOOP END');
            }
       });
    }
};
```

But what I see in console is that "FOR LOOP END" log is displayed before "exif_like END" log. And this causes some unpredictable behaviour in my code.

Is there any solution how to continue for loop after exif_like() function is done?

Comment: Well, you're going to get multiple logs of "for loop end", as that's inside the `for` loop.  Are you sure you're not seeing one of those before a different "exif end" - they should still be appearing in pairs?

Comment: Can we see more of the contents of `exif_like`? Are you using async methods inside of it?

Comment: For example when i upload 3 photos, konsole prints out: "FOR LOOP END", "FOR LOOP END", "FOR LOOP END", "exif_like END", "exif_like END", "exif_like END".. and they should still be appearing in pairs like this: "exif_like END", "FOR LOOP END", "exif_like END", "FOR LOOP END", "exif_like END", "FOR LOOP END"

Comment: With the code you've posted, you should be seeing what you're expecting.  `exif_like` must also be doing something asynchronously with the logging inside that, rather than directly in the function as per your question.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Yes, it does something asynchronously but it is inside exif_like() and I dont see it as a reason to return from this function and continue loop before the last line of exif_like() is executed. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes - anything done asynchronously will get added to the end of the execution queue and not run until all other code has stopped.  For instance, in the code in your question, none of the ajax requests success callbacks will ever begin running until the entire for loop has finished.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Got it, I'm pretty new in JS so thank you, this is very helpfull information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to have `exif_like()` do things in between Ajax calls, just have your `exif_like()` function call the next Ajax request when it finishes.

Using test data from [json placeholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts), something like this would work:

**JavaScript**

```
uploaded_photo = [{name: 1},{name: 2},{name: 6},{name: 8},{name: 9},{name: 11},{name: -1}]
pointer = 0;

function exif_like(path){
    /*working with my image*/ 
  obj = JSON.parse(path)
  if(obj.length > 0) {
    console.log('\t\tdata returned:'+obj[0].id + ' '+obj[0].title)
        console.log('exif_like END for '+obj[0].id);
  } else {
    console.log('\t\tNo data returned')
        console.log('exif_like END');  
  }

  /* Code here can be executed before the next Ajax call */
  console.log('Do stuff before the next ajax call...')

  pointer++;
  if(pointer < uploaded_photo.length) {
    show_uploaded();
  }
}

var show_uploaded = function(){
    console.log('---Start of Ajax call---');

  $.ajax({
    data: { id : uploaded_photo[pointer].name },
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    method: 'GET', 
    complete: function( xhr ){
        console.log('---End of Ajax call---');
      exif_like( xhr.responseText );
    }
  });
};

show_uploaded()
```

**Output**

> ---Start of Ajax call---
>   ---End of Ajax call---
>           data returned:1 sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit
>   exif_like END for 1
>   Do stuff before the next ajax call...
>   ---Start of Ajax call---
>   ---End of Ajax call---
>           data returned:2 qui est esse
>   exif_like END for 2
>   Do stuff before the next ajax call...
>   ---Start of Ajax call---
>   ---End of Ajax call---
>           data returned:6 dolorem eum magni eos aperiam quia
>   exif_like END for 6
>   Do stuff before the next ajax call...
>   ---Start of Ajax call---
>   ---End of Ajax call---
>           data returned:8 dolorem dolore est ipsam
>   exif_like END for 8
>   Do stuff before the next ajax call...
>   ---Start of Ajax call---
>   ---End of Ajax call---
>           data returned:9 nesciunt iure omnis dolorem tempora et accusantium
>   exif_like END for 9
>   Do stuff before the next ajax call...
>   ---Start of Ajax call---
>   ---End of Ajax call---
>           data returned:11 et ea vero quia laudantium autem
>   exif_like END for 11
>   Do stuff before the next ajax call...
>   ---Start of Ajax call---
>   ---End of Ajax call---
>           No data returned
>   exif_like END

JS Fiddle Example: https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/wwj11udx/3/

Hope that helps!

*Edit: Updated code to use the `complete` function instead, in the event there are requests that don't succeed.

Answer (score 2):

If the remainder of processes return expected results, and `exif_like` actually only performs `console.log()` you could try using `$.when()`

```
$.when(exif_like( path )).then(function() {console.log("FOR LOOP END")})
```

Comment: And if my function returns true in the end, after mentioned console.log(), is it possible to do somethink like this: $.when(exif_like( path ) == true).then(function() {console.log("FOR LOOP END")}) ?

Comment: @PetrBečka Yes, it should be possible to do something like that. though, is this your Question as described at OP and comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35801224/continue-in-for-loop-after-function-is-done-javascript/35801434?noredirect=1#comment59272406_35801224 ? Also note, no value appears to be returned from `exif_like( path )` at `js` at Question ?

Comment: Thank you I'll try. Yes, this is my question.

Comment: Would `exif_like(path)` return `true` only once ?

Comment: missunderstood maybe. yes, only once, in the end of the function

Comment: @PetrBečka `if(exif_like(path)) {// do stuff}`

Answer (score 1):

Replace `for loop` to [while](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_while.asp) loop, condition is until data_photo not empty, prior starting `while` loop create `flag` variable which would be boolean identifier that ajax success handler finished and next ajax can be sent. See code below with commented changes :

```
var show_uploaded = function( data_photo ){
  // Create flag 
  var flag = true;
  var length = data_photo;

  // continue loop execution until data_photo not empty
  while (length){
    if(flag){
        var send_image_name = uploaded_photo[--length].name;
        // Set flag to false, until success executed
        flag = false;
        $.ajax({
            data: { compare : send_image_name },
            url: 'get_panorama.php',
            method: 'POST', // or GET
            success: function( path ){
                exif_like( path );
                console.log('FOR LOOP END');
                // We are ready to perform next ajax, set flag to true.
                flag = true;
            },
            error: function( path ){
                // Error or not we have to set flag to true to allow further iterating
                flag = true;
            }
       });
   }
}
};
```

Comment: @HurricaneHamilton I've added comments to code and link with description of while loop in js

Comment: Thanks for updating the code. It looks like this will start the while loop, send the first ajax request, then skip the rest of the items, because there is no way that me.flag gets set to true before the while loop finishes. Remember that the success and error callbacks are async.

Comment: Yes, you  are right, also new ajax won't be sent and data_photo won't be popped for 1 item until flag became true which means previous ajax shall be in onSuccess or on onError phase.

Comment: It looks very nice but I'm kind of lost from your comments guys, do think this is gonna work in the end?

Comment: @PetrBečka yes it suppose to work, important moment is to keep track value of me.flag to be true when would be ajax finished, because otherwise you can be in trouble with infinitive while loop

Comment: Yes, thank you for your time, it really looks like it works. Solved my problem.